# Ricci Scalar Curvature under conformal transformation

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, curvature, conformal-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

Consider the Klein-Gordon equation in curved spacetime with metric $g$

$$\square_g \phi - \xi R \phi = 0$$

and consider a conformal transformation

$$g \longmapsto \tilde{g} = \Omega^{2} g \quad , \qquad \phi \longmapsto \tilde{\phi} = \Omega^{-1} \phi$$

---

I am trying to prove, that with the choice $\xi = 1/6$ the equation becomes **conformally invariant**. To this end, I calculate both terms explicitely. For the wave operator, I get

$$ \square_{\tilde{g}} \tilde{\phi} = \Omega^{-3}  \square_{g} \phi - \Omega^{-4} ( \square_{g} \Omega ) \phi + (n-4) \Omega^{-4} \big[ g( \nabla \Omega, \nabla \phi ) - \Omega^{-1} g( \nabla \Omega, \nabla \Omega ) \phi \big]$$

In dimension $n=4$ this is

$$ \square_{\tilde{g}} \tilde{\phi} = \Omega^{-3}  \square_{g} \phi - \Omega^{-4} ( \square_{g} \Omega ) \phi$$

So far so good. Now I tried to claculate $\tilde{R}$, for which I got the expression:

$$\tilde{R}\phi = \Omega^{-3} R\phi + \Omega^{-4}\Big[ (2-n) \square_g \Omega + (2-n)\Gamma^{c}_{cd} \nabla^d \Omega - g^{ab} \partial_c \big( g_{ab} \nabla^c \Omega\big) \Big] \phi + \underbrace{(n-4)(n-1)\Omega^{-5}g(\nabla \Omega, \nabla \Omega)\phi}_{= \, 0 \text{  in dimensions n=4}}$$

So in order for this to be conformally invariant, one must have

$$\square_{g} \Omega - \xi \Big[ (2-n) \square_g \Omega + (2-n)\Gamma^{c}_{cd} \nabla^d \Omega - g^{ab} \partial_c \big( g_{ab} \nabla^c \Omega\big) \Big] \overset{!}{=} 0 \tag{$\ast$}$$

This seems wrong. I would instead expect to get something like

$$ \Big( 1 + 2\xi (1-n) \Big)\square_g \Omega  \overset{!}{=} 0 \tag{$\ast \ast$}$$

such that with $\xi = 1/6$ the LHS vanishes as proposed. Am I unable to see a way how to get from $(\ast)$ to $(\ast \ast)$ or is my result on $\tilde{R}$ wrong. Does anyone know some literature where this calculation is carried out, so I can check on when my calculation goes wrong?

Comment: See the Appendix of Wald's General Relativity for the conformal transformation of $R$

Comment: Thank you very much for that reference. Maybe I am hereby able to sort out my mistake and post it as an answer.

Comment: You may also find part of my answer here helpful https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/601303/the-action-of-the-kaluza-klein-reduction-chapter-4-of-d-branes-clifford-johns/601845#601845